# Python > PHP - Download files and folders overwriting

Tags: php, python, file, web, download

I develop some python applications so I know how to do this in python locally, but am working with some PHP developers (I know nothing of PHP) who say this can't be done in PHP. This is the idea: A php driven remote website which creates / hosts files. Using a web browser I want to download from this website a series of folders and files onto the local machine overwriting already existing files/folders with the same name. So in my browser I click on a download button which asks me to browse to a local or network folder to download the folders and files to. Currently we are just downloading a single .zip file containing all these files and folders which we have to unzip and manually move, copy paste, etc, very messy and cumbersome. There must be a better way with PHP and some other language?

Comment: You want to create the folders and download the files directly onto the Client (Browser) machine? Like a local program?

Comment: Yes, the files and folder are created on the remote server then downloaded onto the local client via a browser.

Comment: You mean create directly the folders and copy the files on the client machine? Without the client intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to access from a PHP (server-side language) to the Client Machine (from a Browser) and manipulate directly his file system, hard drive, or something like that. This is not the way it works.

Just think about it for a moment, if it could be accomplish, we have serious security threat, for example we visit a page like somebadassdude.com and they have a PHP script that create unlimited folders and files to fill up all our HD... and that is soft.

But hopefully the browsers dont allow this by security design.

Look at this:
[image: Web Diagram]

As you can see at the Diagram, the Browser and the Server response each other through HTTP Requests & Responses. There's no a communication between them like a local program running at the Client OS. You treat with his Browser, and there's no way to command the Browser to manipulate the client hard-disk, and if that can happend, look at the security consern that I mentioned before.

To be more clearer, your PHP script is running at your server, not at the client machine. It only response when a user/browser request a specific resource at your server, and response with a HTTP Response, and it can contain HTML, or Json, or a File (to be downloaded or visualized by external program), or whatever.

You have limited options:

- If it is something for a Intranet, or
  local network, and you have access to that network, locally or
  remotely like with a VPN access. You could share a folder over
  network, in that way you can use a Php Script or Python script in
  order to create the folders and copy the files to it, without have to
  download a zip, and unzip manually from the Browser.
- Using a Java Applet. Why? Because a Java Applet runs
  on the Client Side, so you have access to his computer (if the user
  allow it), and you certeinly can manipulate (create, delete, read,
  etc. folders and files) his hard-drive. So when the user choose the files to download,
  you fire the Java Applet, and let em request to the server the files
  that the user has marked. When you have the files downloaded, create
  or overwrite the files on the client machine.
- Create and run a program in the Client Machine, in detriment of a Web Page, by this way you gain the needed flexibility. But of course, it have his own complexities.

So IHMO i think the Java Applet maybe is the best suited solution for you:

- Do not have to change much your actual business model
- It doesn't require a large time investment.
- It is cross-platform, Java can work on a plenty of operating systems, and Java Applets in the most popular browsers.

By the way, I personally dislike Java, but it's a tool, and you have to use the right tool for a job.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so is there anyway we could get this to work with the intervention of something running on the local network / local client, python, etc, which could then automatically do the end bit... somehow...?

Comment: @speedyrazor You can use a Java Applet, it can run locally on the Client Machine and certainly can do the tasks you want, like manipulate his file system.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how would this Java Applet work with the php download?

Comment: You code the Java Applet to interact through HTTP Requests with your server. So ie the user mark files to download, you save the list of files, and just wait for the Java Applet request, once the Java Applet contact the server requesting what files has to be downloaded, you just read what files user previously request and serve that files. Java Applet download that files and create the folder paths and copy the files into. Anyway, you are sure you want to keep with this? Cheers

Comment: Is this for a intranet? At your job? Or for final clients?

Comment: Just for something I am working on. So just to clarify: Remote server PHP based webite creates files and folders, then a client web-browser hits a download button which then prompts for a download destination, and then downloads the separate files and folders, overwriting duplicates using a Java applet. This would not be on an intranet, but over the internet.